# Attempted to call an undefined method named "renderView" of class

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm pretty new in php symfony2. I want to manage one class for sending emails.

services.yml:

```
   mail_helper:
      class: HelpBundle\MailSender\EmailManager
      arguments: ['@mailer','@templating']
```

EmailManager:

```
class EmailManager
{
protected $mailer;
protected $templating;

public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer,$templating)
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
    $this->templating = $templating;
}

public function sendEmail($fromEmail,$toEmail,$subject,$comments,$status)
{
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setFrom($fromEmail)
        ->setTo($toEmail)
        ->setBody($this->templating->renderView('HelpBundle:Emails:add-comment.html.twig', array('comments' => $comments,
            'status' => $status,
            'subject' => $subject)))
    ;
    $this->mailer->send($message);
   }
 }
```

In my controller I have called like this:

```
public newAction()
{
$mailer = $this->get('mail_helper');
    $mailer->sendEmail($fromEmail,$toEmail,$subject,$comments,$ticketStatus);
}
```

Error when controller action is called is next:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "renderView" of class "HelpBundle\MailSender\EmailManager".

I want to understand how I can fix this ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to inject into your service a templating so in services.yml use:

```
arguments: ["@mailer", "@templating"]
```

and then use it in your service:

```
public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, $templating)
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
    $this->templating = $templating;
}

public function sendEmail($fromEmail, $toEmail, $subject, $comments, $status)
{
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setFrom($fromEmail)
        ->setTo($toEmail)
        ->setBody($this->templating->render('
                 HelpBundle:Emails:add-comment.html.twig', 
                 array('comments' => $comments,
                       'status' => $status,
                       'subject' => $subject
                 )
             )
        );
    $this->mailer->send($message);
}
```

And change renderView() to render(), because renderView() is controller shortcut

Comment: May you help me how to use it ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Now on Default controller where I am calling service to send an email. Getting next error:  Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Swift_Mailer::newInstance() must be an instance of Swift_Transport, none given, called in C:\wamp\www\help\src\HelpBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php on line 27 and defined
Code is:     /** @var EmailManager */
    protected  $mailer;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->mailer = new EmailManager(\Swift_Mailer::newInstance());

    }

Comment: You are using services in wrong way. Read manual how to use services: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

Comment: Hi @Eimsa, I read that document. Based on that and your example I tried to manage my code, but still have error. Where am I now made mistake ?

Comment: The code I wrote is a service, you have to call it in controller or elsewhere you need. In controller you can call it like that 
$service = $this->get('mail_helper'); and then call send email: $service->sendEmail(params); change params to parameters that you pass to sendEmail method.

Comment: Do you mean something like this ?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me.